# Large file to be read in chunks

Tags: java, java-8, apache-commons

I need a process a large file and insert into Db and don't want to spend lot of ram doing the same. I know we can read line in streaming mode by using apache commons API or buffered reader....bt I wish to insert in DB in  batch mode like 1000 insertions at 1 go and not 1 by 1. ....is reading the file line by line  ,adding to a list ,counting size ,inserting and refreshing the list of lines the only option to achieve this ?

Comment: How large is large?

Comment: Can vary 100-500 mb

Comment: Is it possible to use programs like split on the files to be read? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_(Unix)

Comment: Do you want to make one insert of every line?

Comment: I mentioned I need to insert in batches i.e in chunks hence I want to read also in batches...

Comment: When you talk about “lines”, do you want to imply that this is a text file? Besides that, the JDBC API has support for [specifying large data via streams](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Blob.html) for two decades now, though it is up to the particular database driver how it does the transfer, i.e. whether it will have the entire data in memory or not.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, [Spring-Batch](https://spring.io/projects/spring-batch) fit very well.

Basically, it use `chunk` concept to read/process/write the content. By the way, it can be concurrent for performance.

```java
    @Bean
    protected Step loadFeedDataToDbStep() {
        return stepBuilder.get("load new fincon feed").<com.xxx.Group, FinconFeed>chunk(250)
                .reader(itemReader(OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION))
                .processor(itemProcessor(OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION, OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION_DATE, OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION))
                .writer(itemWriter())
                .listener(archiveListener())
                .build();
    }
```

You can refer to [here](https://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/spring-batch-tutorial/) for more